# Should continuity test be performed when the device is off? Why?

Tags: test, continuity

Can an electronic circuit which is passing currents be tested by a multi-meter's continuity test? Would it be meaningful or harmful? Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A continuity test is like a simplified resistance/ohms measurement. Do you know how such a measurement works ? A basic method is to apply a voltage across the resistor and measure the current OR apply a current and measure the voltage. Then through R = V/I you can calculate the resistance.

Now imagine you're measuring a resistor in this way but at the same time when you are measuring I apply an extra voltage or current. Would the measurement then still be accurate ? This is what happens when you do a continuity test on a device that is still powered. Now imagine I apply 100 V DC but your meter can only handle 10 V when in the continuity test mode. What will happen now ?

Answer (score 5):

Such a test is completely meaningless, and potentially damaging to the meter.
If you want to test continuity or resistance, remove all sources of power, and discharge any stored energy sources.

FakeMustache has explained that, but simply put, the meter is SOURCING a (usually low) test voltage.  If you connect it to something that is already powered, you are connecting the two sources together, and the meter isn't designed to handle external sources in continuity or resistance (or capacitance, or inductance, or any other passive) mode.

When a meter is set to voltage, it presents a very high impedance to the source being measured.  When set to current, it presents a very low impedance, but both are designed specifically to handle reading an active source.  When it is set to measure a passive circuit or device, it must source its own test voltage, and the precision regulated source is easily damaged by external power.

Comment: Can you explain me why it would damage the meter?

Comment: See my answer, if the device is on there is no guarantee that the voltage on the points where you measure is within the safe limit of the meter. Good professional meters can ususally handle high voltages but a cheap meter will almost certainly blow up or at least get damaged. When a device is powered on, the only safe thing to measure are voltages and only when these are expected to be below 50 V or so and also isolated from mains. If this confuses you: ALWAYS power down on the device you measure.

Comment: Even high quality meters are only protected to their listed ratings.  I didn't do it personally, but I did see the results of a Fluke 87, set properly to AC Voltage, inadvertently connected to a 4160 line.  There wasn't a whole lot left.